# Blur on touch. Android application

Tags: android, blur

I am trying to make an application in which the part of the image user touched on the android app gets blurred.

Requirement is like, I should be able to take a snap and then slide over my finger over the points which I need to blur out. Is there any easy way for it. Can I somehow use transparent paint with opacity to accomplish it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @ChintanRathod: I have tried painting over the image. When I slide my finger over the image it draws over the image. What I want to do is that somehow change the Paint object settings such that when I move my finger instead of drawing it just blur the part of the image.

Comment: You can do this, but for that you need to place 2 bitmap one over other. Front will be original. Rear image will be blurred image. Try to search for `erase image on touch`. This will provide you how to erase top image so that rear image come out and user feels that image get blurred. :)

Comment: hey have you soled the problem? i required the same thing

Answer (score 4):

Seems the issue should be solved using [RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html). However, seems that it supports only bitmap blur, so we might need to cut bitmap before blurring. Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988990/android-fast-bitmap-blur) about fast image blur, I was able to achieve surprisingly good performance on Nexus 10 tablet.

The code is following (**note:** it's draft version, I've played with it only for 30 minutes):

```
public class BlurTouchImageView extends View {
    private static final int BLUR_RADIUS = 20;
    // TODO: resources should be used
    private static final int BLUR_SIDE = 300;

    private RenderScript mBlurScript = null;
    private ScriptIntrinsicBlur mIntrinsicScript = null;
    private Bitmap mBitmap = null;
    private Bitmap mBlurredBitmap = null;
    private float mX = -1;
    private float mY = -1;

    public BlurTouchImageView(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public BlurTouchImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public BlurTouchImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    /**
     * Inits our view internal members
     */
    private void init() {
        mBlurScript = RenderScript.create(getContext());
        mIntrinsicScript = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(mBlurScript, Element.U8_4(mBlurScript));
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.gimg);
        mBlurredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(BLUR_SIDE, BLUR_SIDE, mBitmap.getConfig());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
        boolean retval = false;

        mX = event.getX();
        mY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                retval = true;
                invalidate();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                mX = -1;
                mY = - 1;
                retval = true;
                invalidate();
                break;

            default:
                // nothing to do here
                break;
        }

        return retval;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        // Blur bitmap if it's touched

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        if (mX > 0 && mY > 0) {
            // Yeah, it will slooow down drawing, but how else we can prepare needed part of bitmap?
            final Bitmap blurSource = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, (int) mX - BLUR_SIDE / 2, (int) mY - BLUR_SIDE / 2, BLUR_SIDE, BLUR_SIDE);

            final Allocation inAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mBlurScript, blurSource, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_GRAPHICS_TEXTURE);
            final Allocation outAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mBlurScript, mBlurredBitmap);

            mIntrinsicScript.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
            mIntrinsicScript.setInput(inAlloc);
            mIntrinsicScript.forEach(outAlloc);
            outAlloc.copyTo(mBlurredBitmap);

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBlurredBitmap, (int)mX - BLUR_SIDE / 2, (int)mY - BLUR_SIDE / 2, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Result is:

[image: blur example]

Although I was afraid that creating `Bitmap` in `onDraw` will cause big lags, in activity with only this view blur area moves quite smoothly.

Comment: Can you please tell how to use this code to blur a image.

Comment: It's little bit different, seems there should be another question about it

Comment: I am using this code to blur a image on touch but it is now working for me.I am not able to understand how to use this.

Comment: I do not know from where i will get full code.Can you help me to get it.

Comment: In example in the answer the full app code is simple, there's activity with single custom view, that's all.