# How to blur an image

Tags: java, android, eclipse, blur

I'm wondering if that is possible to blur a bitmap or a drawable.
Like the app [muzei](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.muzei) is doing.is it possible ?
ive tried to use some image effects class ive found but they were helpless...
thanks to the helpers

Comment: For a simplistic version, try to make each output pixel a function of the corresponding input pixel and its neighbors out to some radius.  For example, some sort of "average" - you can play with the radius and if the average should be weighted by the distance from the subject pixel.

Comment: Did you read the app description? All the code is available at http://code.muzei.co You can find exactly how they did it.

Comment: Maybe this can help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589760/how-do-i-blur-an-image

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101908/fastest-method-for-blurring-an-image-in-java

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799451/java-blocking-focus-from-jcomponent

Comment: http://trickyandroid.com/advanced-blurring-techniques/

Comment: Here's the relevant piece in muzei that does the bitmap blurring: https://github.com/romannurik/muzei/blob/master/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/muzei/render/ImageBlurrer.java

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible. Try [Android StackBlur](https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur) library.

According to its documentation, to use this library, you must do the following:

*First initialize your StackBlurManager to load a sample image:*

```
_stackBlurManager = new StackBlurManager(getBitmapFromAsset(this, "android_platform_256.png"));
```

*Process using a certain radius with the following line:*

```
_stackBlurManager.process(progress*5);
```

*and finally obtain the image and load it into an ImageView or any other component:*

```
_imageView.setImageBitmap(_stackBlurManager.returnBlurredImage());
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The answer is already accepted, but I'll expand my suggestion anyway if someone is interested. Thanks for the feedback.