# Blur the image efficiently in Android

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, blur

Hello I am developing the android application where I need to blur the bitmap. Currently the code which I am using to blur the bitmap is making application slow when I run it on the device. I have a `ListView` where each row background I need to blur that background bitmap then set it.

This below code takes around 3-4 seconds to blur a one bitmap, here in my case (ListView) when items are 25+ then it really makes application very slow and display the ANR dialog.

Sample code :

```
/**
 * Blur the bitmap
 * @param sentBitmap
 * @param radius
 * @return blur bitmap
 */
public static Bitmap fastblur(Bitmap sentBitmap, int radius) {
    Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);

    if (radius < 1) {
        return (null);
    }

    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();

    int[] pix = new int[w * h];
    Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
    bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

    int wm = w - 1;
    int hm = h - 1;
    int wh = w * h;
    int div = radius + radius + 1;

    int r[] = new int[wh];
    int g[] = new int[wh];
    int b[] = new int[wh];
    int rsum, gsum, bsum, x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw;
    int vmin[] = new int[Math.max(w, h)];

    int divsum = (div + 1) >> 1;
    divsum *= divsum;
    int dv[] = new int[256 * divsum];
    for (i = 0; i < 256 * divsum; i++) {
        dv[i] = (i / divsum);
    }

    yw = yi = 0;

    int[][] stack = new int[div][3];
    int stackpointer;
    int stackstart;
    int[] sir;
    int rbs;
    int r1 = radius + 1;
    int routsum, goutsum, boutsum;
    int rinsum, ginsum, binsum;

    for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
        for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
            p = pix[yi + Math.min(wm, Math.max(i, 0))];
            sir = stack[i + radius];
            sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
            sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);
            rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);
            rsum += sir[0] * rbs;
            gsum += sir[1] * rbs;
            bsum += sir[2] * rbs;
            if (i > 0) {
                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];
            } else {
                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];
            }
        }
        stackpointer = radius;

        for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {

            r[yi] = dv[rsum];
            g[yi] = dv[gsum];
            b[yi] = dv[bsum];

            rsum -= routsum;
            gsum -= goutsum;
            bsum -= boutsum;

            stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
            sir = stack[stackstart % div];

            routsum -= sir[0];
            goutsum -= sir[1];
            boutsum -= sir[2];

            if (y == 0) {
                vmin[x] = Math.min(x + radius + 1, wm);
            }
            p = pix[yw + vmin[x]];

            sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
            sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);

            rinsum += sir[0];
            ginsum += sir[1];
            binsum += sir[2];

            rsum += rinsum;
            gsum += ginsum;
            bsum += binsum;

            stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
            sir = stack[(stackpointer) % div];

            routsum += sir[0];
            goutsum += sir[1];
            boutsum += sir[2];

            rinsum -= sir[0];
            ginsum -= sir[1];
            binsum -= sir[2];

            yi++;
        }
        yw += w;
    }
    for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
        yp = -radius * w;
        for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
            yi = Math.max(0, yp) + x;

            sir = stack[i + radius];

            sir[0] = r[yi];
            sir[1] = g[yi];
            sir[2] = b[yi];

            rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);

            rsum += r[yi] * rbs;
            gsum += g[yi] * rbs;
            bsum += b[yi] * rbs;

            if (i > 0) {
                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];
            } else {
                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];
            }

            if (i < hm) {
                yp += w;
            }
        }
        yi = x;
        stackpointer = radius;
        for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            // Preserve alpha channel: ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] )
            pix[yi] = (0xff000000 & pix[yi]) | (dv[rsum] << 16)
                    | (dv[gsum] << 8) | dv[bsum];

            rsum -= routsum;
            gsum -= goutsum;
            bsum -= boutsum;

            stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
            sir = stack[stackstart % div];

            routsum -= sir[0];
            goutsum -= sir[1];
            boutsum -= sir[2];

            if (x == 0) {
                vmin[y] = Math.min(y + r1, hm) * w;
            }
            p = x + vmin[y];

            sir[0] = r[p];
            sir[1] = g[p];
            sir[2] = b[p];

            rinsum += sir[0];
            ginsum += sir[1];
            binsum += sir[2];

            rsum += rinsum;
            gsum += ginsum;
            bsum += binsum;

            stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
            sir = stack[stackpointer];

            routsum += sir[0];
            goutsum += sir[1];
            boutsum += sir[2];

            rinsum -= sir[0];
            ginsum -= sir[1];
            binsum -= sir[2];

            yi += w;
        }
    }

    Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
    bitmap.setPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

    return (bitmap);
}
```

Calling this method looks like

```
fastblur(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(zis), 50)
```

I checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14988991/2455259 but that works above API Level 17.

Any idea to blur the bitmap very fast and that works in API level 8+ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you posted looks efficient, but a blur radius of 50 is rather large. Couldn't you scale down the image first?

Answer (score 2):

This code work perfect for me.

```
Bitmap tempbg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.b1); //Load a  background.
Bitmap final_Bitmap = BlurImage(tempbg);

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
Bitmap BlurImage (Bitmap input)
{
    try
    {
    RenderScript  rsScript = RenderScript.create(getApplicationContext());
    Allocation alloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rsScript, input);

    ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rsScript, Element.U8_4(rsScript));
    blur.setRadius(21);
    blur.setInput(alloc);

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Allocation outAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rsScript, result);

    blur.forEach(outAlloc);
    outAlloc.copyTo(result);

    rsScript.destroy();
    return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        return input;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but setRadius limit between 0 to 23.
    blur.setRadius(21);

Comment: For what you are using `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced in Andorid, Yet I may assist from an Image Processing Approach.

If you blur with large radius it means you remove most of the details of image.
Hence a Pre Ptrocessing step of the decimation of the image and the applying smaller radius blur and then upscaling might be much faster.