# How to blur background images in Android

Tags: java, android

What is the best way to blur background images like the image below? I saw some code and libraries but their are a couple of years old or like BlurBehind library, but it doesn't give the same effect.

[image]

Comment: Most people just roll their own or use an existing library.  That's what I'd suggest.  You can find fast box blur implementations online pretty easily. Or, just pre-render your blurred image if you're not animating the blur.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795483/create-blurry-transparent-background-effect? Worked like a charm for me

Comment: There are two way to achieve. 1) You can use FrameLayout to which you can set blur background. 2) You can use latest Blur library which i have !

Comment: Thanks @StephenG that answer actually helped me a lot.

Comment: Kotlin version for people may need: check this repository on [Github](https://github.com/HJaliliani/BlurActivityBackground)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is use a library. Take a look at this one: https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry

With the library you only need to do this:

```
Blurry.with(context)
  .radius(10)
  .sampling(8)
  .color(Color.argb(66, 255, 255, 0))
  .async()
  .onto(rootView);
```

Comment: I saw that this library as "Trending in github"... but I don't know if is just the screenshots (I didn't try it yet) but the screenshots are a little bit pixelated.

Comment: I think it is related to the fact that the description images are Gifs. You should try, it should works fine.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get any effect using your sample, I even messed with the values, but nothing happened

Comment: bro what is rootView.. when I.set my ImageView to onto it shows an error

Comment: It doesn't work. This sample didn't work at all (strange). Then I tried sample from their repo and there's white image only.. :(

Comment: i want to make video view blur same way,is there any way to do this??

Answer (score 30):

This is an easy way to blur Images Efficiently with Android's RenderScript that I found on this [article](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-blur-images-efficiently-with-androids-renderscript)

1. Create a Class called BlurBuilder

   ```
   public class BlurBuilder {
     private static final float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.4f;
     private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 7.5f;

     public static Bitmap blur(Context context, Bitmap image) {
       int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
       int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);

       Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
       Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

       RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
       ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
       Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
       Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
       theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
       theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
       theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
       tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

       return outputBitmap;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Copy any image to your drawable folder
3. Use BlurBuilder in your activity like this:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

       mContainerView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
       Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);
       Bitmap blurredBitmap = BlurBuilder.blur( this, originalBitmap );
       mContainerView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), blurredBitmap));
   ```
4. Renderscript is included into support v8 enabling this answer down to api 8. To enable it using gradle include these lines into your gradle file (from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21052060/2091181))

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       ...
       renderscriptTargetApi *your target api*
       renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
   }
   ```
5. Result

[image]

Comment: thanks for you answer , i just want to add that this solution requires API 19 , to enable the support library which supports API 8 see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22976675/5519369

Comment: and what if we want to increase the blur power? what to change

Comment: @Sam Set `BLUR_RADIUS` to the value you want.

Comment: what happens if I change **BITMAP_SCALE** value?

Answer (score 22):

You can use:

```java
Glide.with(getContext()).load(R.mipmap.bg)
     .apply(bitmapTransform(new BlurTransformation(22)))
     .into((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imBg));
```

This requires the following addition to your `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.0.0'
```

Comment: For those who got unresolved reference error for `BlurTransformation` you need to add this `implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.0.0` to your gradle

Comment: It works, But This one doesn't seem clean. Use other module if you want foggy feeling. This one shows strong edges. Just inner part is blurry.

Comment: 3rd party library dependency should be added into the answer instead of comment.

Comment: Where is bitmapTransform() method ?

Answer (score 10):

Android 12, Preview 1 comes with built-in blur feature. We need not depend on external library now. Here is the code

```
imageView.setRenderEffect(
        RenderEffect.createBlurEffect(
            20.0f, 20.0f, SHADER_TITLE_MODE
        )
)
```

Comment: How to use window background blur? my test not work.

Comment: I suspect we should use [RenderScript](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute), otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: For those who want to return the imageView to its original state:  imageView.setRenderEffect(
        RenderEffect.createBlurEffect(
           1.0f, 1.0f, SHADER_TITLE_MODE
        )
)

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to achieve this is given below,

I)

```
Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
                        .load(Your Path)   
                        .override(15, 15) // (change according to your wish)
                        .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                        .into(image.score);
```

else you can follow the code below..

II)

1.Create a class.(Code is given below)

```
public class BlurTransformation extends BitmapTransformation {

    private RenderScript rs;

    public BlurTransformation(Context context) {
        super( context );

        rs = RenderScript.create( context );
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap transform(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap toTransform, int outWidth, int outHeight) {
        Bitmap blurredBitmap = toTransform.copy( Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true );

        // Allocate memory for Renderscript to work with
        Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(
            rs, 
            blurredBitmap, 
            Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_FULL, 
            Allocation.USAGE_SHARED
        );
        Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());

        // Load up an instance of the specific script that we want to use.
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        script.setInput(input);

        // Set the blur radius
        script.setRadius(10);

        // Start the ScriptIntrinisicBlur
        script.forEach(output);

        // Copy the output to the blurred bitmap
        output.copyTo(blurredBitmap);

        toTransform.recycle();

        return blurredBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return "blur";
    }
}
```

2.Set image to ImageView using Glide.

eg:

```
Glide.with(this)
     .load(expertViewDetailsModel.expert.image)
     .asBitmap()
     .transform(new BlurTransformation(this))
     .into(ivBackground);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Works only on Android 12 as of now so is not a universal solution yet**

To blur a image

1 Set your target SDK and compile SDK to Android S in build.gradle

2.Use [Render Effect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RenderEffect)

3.set blur as follows

```
your_view.setRenderEffect(
     RenderEffect.createBlurEffect(
     30f, //radius X
     30f, //Radius Y
     Shader.TileMode.[X]// X=CLAMP,DECAL,MIRROR,REPEAT
)
```

4.The 4 types of blend mode are

CLAMP- Replicate the edge color if the shader draws outside of its original bounds

DECAL- Render the shader's image pixels only within its original bounds

MIRROR- Repeat the shader's image horizontally and vertically, alternating mirror images so that adjacent images always seam.

REPEAT - Repeat the shader's image horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 2):

Android 12 (Api level 31) has new Theme parameters to apply for windows to blur background:

```xml
<style name="BlurryTheme" parent="...">
    <item name="android:windowBackgroundBlurRadius">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowBlurBehindEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBlurBehindRadius">10dp</item>
</style>
```

And also new API for `View` to apply blur effect `android.view.View#setRenderEffect`:

```
imageView.setRenderEffect(
    RenderEffect.createBlurEffect(
        20.0f, 20.0f, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Tested on Android 9 and 12. Use Glide library to shrink the bitmap.

```
// Glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.0'
```

```
Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(favorite.coverImage).into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(2, 2) {
                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                        ivContentHolder.setImageDrawable(BitmapDrawable(itemBinding.root.context.resources, resource))
                    }

                    override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                        ivContentHolder.setImageDrawable(null)
                    }
```

CustomTarget(2, 2) is the trick. The lower the value the more the blur effect. Basically its used to shrink the image size. Then all you have to do is set the shrunk bitmap to your imageView. And most important is to set ScaleType of the imageView to CenterCrop.

```xml
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_content_holder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@color/purple_700"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

The result will look something like this. [Blur Effect Demo](https://github.com/Singularity-Coder/Ideal-API-Call)
[image: iOS like Blur effect]

Answer (score 0):

this might not be the most efficient solution but I had to use it since the wasabeef/Blurry library didn't work for me. this could be handy if you intend to have some getting-blurry animation:

1- you need to have 2 versions of the picture, normal one and the blurry one u make with photoshop or whatever

2- set the images fit on each other in your xml, then one of them could be seen and that's the upper one

3- set fadeout animation on the upper one:

```
final Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        fadeOut.setDuration(1000);


        fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {upperone.setVisibility(View.GONE);}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        });

        upperone.startAnimation(fadeOut);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Glide for load and transform into blur image,
1) for only one view,

```
val requestOptions = RequestOptions()
                requestOptions.transform(BlurTransformation(50)) // 0-100
Glide.with(applicationContext).setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                        .load(imageUrl).into(view)
```

2) if you are using the adapter to load an image in the item, you should write your code in the if-else block, otherwise, it will make all your images blurry.

```
 if(isBlure){
  val requestOptions = RequestOptions()
                requestOptions.transform(BlurTransformation(50))
                Glide.with(applicationContext).setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                        .load(imageUrl).into(view )
}else{
 val requestOptions = RequestOptions()
            Glide.with(applicationContext).setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions).load(imageUrl).into(view)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have a view with Background color as black and set alpha for the view as 0.7 or whatever as per your requirement.

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/onboardingimg1">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/opacityFilter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:alpha="0.7">
    </View>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't give the same effect as blur

Comment: Also, this blurs text views that get added as children.

Comment: Blur effect is different then opacity effect.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code..
Put This Code in On Create..

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
                    new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
       Url="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTIur0ueOsmVmFVmAA-SxcCT7bTodZb3eCNbiShIiP9qWCWk3mDfw";
//        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(Url).into(img_profile);
//        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(Url).into(img_c_profile);

        bitmap=getBitmapFromURL(Url);
        Bitmap blurred = blurRenderScript(bitmap, 12);//second parametre is radius
        img_profile.setImageBitmap(blurred);
```

Create Below Methods.. Just Copy Past..

```
 public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            return null;
        }
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private Bitmap blurRenderScript(Bitmap smallBitmap, int radius) {

        try {
            smallBitmap = RGB565toARGB888(smallBitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                smallBitmap.getWidth(), smallBitmap.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(getActivity());

        Allocation blurInput = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, smallBitmap);
        Allocation blurOutput = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, bitmap);

        ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript,
                Element.U8_4(renderScript));
        blur.setInput(blurInput);
        blur.setRadius(radius); // radius must be 0 < r <= 25
        blur.forEach(blurOutput);

        blurOutput.copyTo(bitmap);
        renderScript.destroy();

        return bitmap;

    }

    private Bitmap RGB565toARGB888(Bitmap img) throws Exception {
        int numPixels = img.getWidth() * img.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[numPixels];

        //Get JPEG pixels.  Each int is the color values for one pixel.
        img.getPixels(pixels, 0, img.getWidth(), 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());

        //Create a Bitmap of the appropriate format.
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        //Set RGB pixels.
        result.setPixels(pixels, 0, result.getWidth(), 0, 0, result.getWidth(), result.getHeight());
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

This might be a very late reply but I hope it helps someone.

1. You can use third party libs such as RenderScript/Blurry/etc.
2. If you do not want to use any third party libs, you can do the below using alpha(setting alpha to 0 means complete blur and 1 means same as existing).

**Note(If you are using point 2)** : While setting alpha to the background, it will blur the whole layout. To avoid this, **create a new xml containing drawable and set alpha here to 0.5 (or value of your wish) and use this drawable name (name of file) as the background.**

For example, use it as below (say file name is bgndblur.xml):

```xml
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:shape="rectangle"
android:src="@drawable/registerscreenbackground" 
android:alpha="0.5">
```

Use the below in your layout:

```xml
<....
 android:background="@drawable/bgndblur">
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: This is not blurring.

Answer (score -5):

You can quickly get to blur effect by doing the following.

// Add this to build.gradle app //

```
Compile ' com.github.jgabrielfreitas:BlurImageView:1.0.1 '
```

// Add to XML

```
<com.jgbrielfreitas.core.BlurImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_blur_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

//Add this to java

```
Import com.jgabrielfreitas.core.BlueImageView;
```

// Under public class *activity name * //

```
BlurImageView myBlurImage;
```

// Under Oncreate//

```
myBlurImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_blur_image)
MyBlurImage.setBlue(5)
```

I hope that helps someone