# App not working for Lollipop

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, renderscript

I am using stack blur library for my app it works fine for api 16 but when I tried to run the app in api 21 the app is getting crashed. I tried to fix the library gradle but it is giving me error message while compiling. This is the library that I am [using](https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur)

Error
[image] 
My App gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.neelay.level34"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
repositories {
maven { url 'http://Manabu-GT.github.com/GlassView/mvn-repo' }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.ms.square:glassview:0.1.0'
compile 'com.romainpiel.shimmer:library:1.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':StackBlur')
}
```

And Stack blur gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    renderscriptTargetApi 21
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}

 task nativeLibsToJar(type: Zip, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
baseName 'native-libs'
extension 'jar'
from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
from fileTree(dir: 'renderscript', include: '**/*.so')
into 'lib/'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
}
```

I chanded my stack blur gradle

```
 compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

defaultConfig {
    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
```

these are the lines that I changed.

Comment: may be some of the resource file missing for version 21. can you check them?

Comment: How I can know what files are missing?  It is not even given in the demo of the lib.

Comment: there is no file named raw in the lib ,and what can be inside the file blur?

Comment: yes i checked it. seems to be raw folder is missing in the res dir. did you try the demo application in lollipop?

Comment: No i used only in api16

Comment: can you try demo in lollipop since project last updated was 3 years. project may be abandoned.

Comment: some of the file are updated 6 month back also

Comment: first of all this is not supported on higher device.. try different library.. its only supported lower than 21.0.2 or you can use alternative for both lower and above api

Comment: make condition like if your api is => 21{ then not to use this library.. use different one}else{ use this library}

Comment: look at this solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641973/how-to-blur-background-images-in-android. this is the easiest way to blur images.