# How to blur a view or layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-xml, blur

I'm trying to blur a view or layout like the example i have below. So far I have only seen examples of bluring images and im confused on how to implement a blur on a layout. I hope you guys can help!

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: Hey check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795483/create-blurry-transparent-background-effect and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641973/how-to-blur-background-images-in-android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to blur background images in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641973/how-to-blur-background-images-in-android)