# How to create a faded background from the main image?

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have a picture and I want the background to be a blur from the main image how can i do this? It's like this:
[Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KDt_cXUd_zdFH_P3sZdlHTLwbaGK2P-a/view?usp=drivesdk)

And I tried using setAlpha but it just darkened the image.

Thank !

Comment: First result for "android blur background". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641973/how-to-blur-background-images-in-android

You could set blur as background, and your image as sourceDrawable("src" in xml) if you wanna do it with the same ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the alpha property of the ImageView something like this:

```
android:alpha="0.3" //set value between 0-1 of your choice
```

or by your code:

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.yourimageViewID);
imageView.setAlpha(0.3f);
```