# How to blur the background image of imageview in android

Tags: java, android, imageview

I want to `blur` the `background` of an imageview.
I am using single `image-view` right now. So is it possible to do that in single image-view or should i have to use two image-view's (one for the background and one for the foreground).

I want to achieve something like this

[image]

Comment: can you illustrate with screenshots adding here?

Comment: do you want to blur only single imageview ?

Comment: you mean setAlpha?

Comment: An easy way to do this is through https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry 
if you dont mind importing a library to your codebase.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to blur background images in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641973/how-to-blur-background-images-in-android)

Comment: @Dan Artillaga No

Comment: @Wini yes the background image should be blur and foreground will remain same

Comment: @M.Waqas Pervez i want exactly same but is it possible to do it without using any library?

Comment: @prakharshrivastava i added my answer

Comment: @prakharshrivastava is this what you wanted?

Comment: The image in the background imageview is stretched too much. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @prakharshrivastava try adjusting `Scaletype` or just remove it...you need to adjust your tags according to your image ...

Comment: @prakharshrivastava it is beacause of `Scaletype`...i hope you get it

Answer (score 2):

try----->>

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout android:clipToPadding="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="400dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"      // scaletype depends upon image you adjust or dont put
    android:id="@+id/customProfileGridImg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
        />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"      
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"     // scaletype depends upon image you adjust or dont put
    android:src="@drawable/nature"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**java**-->

```
public class MainActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 25f;

ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mjhgf);

     imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.customProfileGridImg);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.nature);
    Bitmap blurredBitmap = blur(bitmap);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);


}

public Bitmap blur(Bitmap image) {
    if (null == image) return null;

    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image);
    final RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(this);
    Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, image);
    Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);

   //Intrinsic Gausian blur filter
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
    theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
    theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
    theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
    tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
    return outputBitmap;
}
  }
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso for image related tasks. It has many useful predefined functionalities. For your reference checkout this link how to blur using picasso.[Picasso image blur](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-image-blur-using-picaso-4fb7592e1fa6)