# Blur imageView in Android

Tags: android, imageview, blur

I am using the method answered in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42504557/9183599) I implemented the dependencies into `build.gradle` but when I paste the code it shows me errors that I don't have class name `Glide`. How do I work around this so I can make my `ImageView` blur?

I have simple code for learning purposes

```
imageView4.setOnClickListener {
      if (!haveImage) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Image not imported yet!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      } else {
         val imgUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.myapplication/" + R.drawable.ic_launcher)
         imageView4.setImageURI(imgUri)
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to specify Glide in `gradle` like this

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

Apply the transformation

```
        Glide.with(this@MainActivity)
           .asBitmap()
           .load(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
           .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(BlurTransformation(25, 3)))
           .into(imageView)
```

Comment: It shows error for 'BlurTransformations' (create abstract function 'BlurTransf...'), also 'setImageURI' doesn't work anymore. Could you please give more in-depth answer? Thanks alot!

Comment: You need another gradle dependency. Add glide-transformations and it should work.

Comment: BOOM that fixes the problem, i am sorry for the earlier comment about the 'setImageURI' it was my mistake in the xml file :)))

Answer (score 0):

With the new Android API Level 31 (Android 12) you can use method `android.view.View#setRenderEffect()` to apply blur effect to a view:

```
imageView.setRenderEffect(
    RenderEffect.createBlurEffect(
        20.0f, 20.0f, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
    )
)
```