# Android: Create Faded Background Image

Tags: android

I want to create an android screen like this-
The background image is faded and has a linear layout over it which gives the image a faded look.

[image]

Comment: Give `image` as `background` to `ViewGroup` and set its opacity using `alpha`

Comment: Make image as background to your layout, and give it alpha property, it will work

Comment: no, alpha will not work

Comment: Edit it with some image editor. Gaussian blur + black filter. Then add it as a background in the layout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795483/create-blurry-transparent-background-effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a faded Image but a blurred image.
Changing alpha will fade image not blur it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988990/android-fast-bitmap-blur) might help

Answer (score 1):

It's basically a blurred image background. You can use tools like Photoshop to add the blur effect or if you are looking for dynamic blurs, you could use the [StackBlur](https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur) library.

Simply initialize with the image that you want to blur,

```
_stackBlurManager = new StackBlurManager(getBitmapFromAsset(this, "yourFile.png"));
```

And set the blur radius,

```
_stackBlurManager.process(progress*5);
```

And then set the blurred as a background for your layout or `ImageView`.

```
_imageView.setImageBitmap(_stackBlurManager.returnBlurredImage() );
```