# How to blur the specific part of image without using Render Script,as my minsdk is 14.

Tags: android, image

I want to blur the specific part of image in android without using Render Script. I am using minSdkVersion 14. I want to make image blur dynamically like image processing apps do. Dynamically means there should be one movable view on top of image and inside that view, Image will be clear and other than that it should be blurred.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10028267/1377145

Comment: Thanks. Nice algorithm. But this algorithm is blurring the whole image, I want some part of Image to be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first blur the bitmap:

[Android: fast bitmap blur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988990/android-fast-bitmap-blur)

Then you have to apply image masking to that bitmap by using transparent in the middle.

[Masking(crop) image in frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614542/maskingcrop-image-in-frame)

Then you should put this bitmap as drawale to your movable imageview.

Comment: Can this be done in one step in Renderscript?