# How to do image blur on touch (progressively)?

Tags: android

I want to blur a portion of bitmap and set into image view. But I am not getting any reference of the same.

Comment: 'How to do' is not a good question. Show the efforts you tried.

Comment: Do you want to blur an image on touch?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score -1):

Took me 40 seconds to find the solution in stackoverflow, Please use search :)

Use the blur from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028267/5618671

**(Make sure to +1 Yahel, the user that posted the blur solution)**

Get your Bitmap (can get it from your existing imageView), Call the fast blur when imageView has been clicked, and set the imageView with the new blurred Bitmap :

**example**

```
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //GET BITMAP FROM IMAGEVIEW
            BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmapFromImageView = drawable.getBitmap();
            Bitmap blurredBitmap = fastblur(bitmapFromImageView, BITMAP_SCALE, BLUR_RADIUS)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);
        }
    });
```

P.S Make sure imageview is declared final:

```
final ImageView imageView;
```

Comment: This is doing whole image blur. I want blur some part of image. with ontouch listners

Comment: Do you want blur where user clicked? Please be more specific.
This is how to get the location on screen of the user's click:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476840/5618671

This is for partial blur:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263734/5618671
 Combine those and vouila!

Comment: I Want a blur effect like Point Blur application. Please refer this application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.pointblur.android.app.quick&hl=en